# Como dar zoom em uma imagem ao passar o mouse em cima?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou criando um site de tattoos que contém uma galeria de fotos. Eu gostaria que quando o usuário passasse o mouse por cima de uma imagem ela fosse ampliada para um tamanho maior.

Sou iniciante em montagem de sites, entendo um pouco de HTML e CSS; no entanto, não tenho conhecimento de JavaScript.

Comment: Tem uns plugins jQuery bem bacanas pra fazer essas coisas. Um dos mais interessantes que já ví é o [jQuery Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/). Além de bonito e funcional a sua "instalação" é bem fácil, tem o passo-a-passo ali no site. Se tiver problemas avise.

Answer (score 4):

Existem diversas formas de resolver seu problema, mesmo todas derivando de uma única. Pode usar soluções prontas - *pesquisando no Google, encontrará várias bibliotecas livres e/ou pagas* - ou criá-las do zero.

**Aqui proponho um exemplo** para que você possa trabalhar em cima. Ele apenas amplia/reduz a imagem sem grande beleza envolvida.

---

```js
var entidade = document.getElementById('imagem');

// Altere o número para a apliação/redução desejada
var fator_lupa = 2;

entidade.onmouseover = function () { this.style.width = (this.clientWidth * fator_lupa) + "px"; };

entidade.onmouseout = function () { this.style.width = (this.clientWidth / fator_lupa) + "px"; };
```

```html
<img id="imagem" width="200" src="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
```

---

Aqui tem um link do ***JSFiddle*** para exemplo do código em funcionamento no caso da pré-visualização do SOpt não funcionar: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfcandidofilho/nyaf39g0/embedded/result/)

**Espero ter ajudado!**

Answer (score 3):

É possível fazer sem uso JavaScript, o que acho mais bacana. Usando a propriedade `transform:scale` do CSS3:

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

[Fonte com mais informações](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757620/1267304).

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<img src="/img/fundo.jpg" >
```

CSS:

```
img:hover{
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
  }
```